# Support Swift in SDK with deployment target 7.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks, static-libraries

I want to add Swift interface to an SDK. Deployment target of the SDK should be iOS 7.0 which means that we can't use a framework. Adding Swift files to a static library looks impossible too.

However, I see that there are SDKs (e.g. Crashlytics) that support 7.0 and have Swift interface. They look like static libraries, so how do they integrate Swift interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's done via modules:

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html

http://blog.bjhomer.com/2015/05/defining-modules-for-custom-libraries.html